non-isomorphic unitary irreps are orthogonal, and related concepts
Let $ N $ be a normal matrix. Let $ v_i,v_j $ be eigenvectors of $ N $ with eigenvalues $ \lambda_i, \lambda_j $. If $ \lambda_i \neq \lambda_j $ are distinct then $ v_i \cdot v_j =0$ are orthogonal.
Let $ (\pi,V) $ be a unitary representation. Suppose that $ v_i, v_j \in V $ transform in the irreducible subrepresentations $ (\pi_i,V_i), (\pi_j,V_j) $ of $ \pi $. If $ \pi_i $ and $ \pi_j $ are not isomorphic irreps then $ v_i \cdot v_j =0$ are orthogonal.
What is the relationship between these two facts? Is there a way to unify them?
Background: Just summarizing the argument given in the comments by Joppy proving the earlier statement that "Let $ (\pi,V) $ be a unitary representation. Suppose that $ v_i, v_j \in V $ transform in the irreducible subrepresentations $ (\pi_i,V_i), (\pi_j,V_j) $ of $ \pi $. If $ \pi_i $ and $ \pi_j $ are not isomorphic irreps then $ v_i \cdot v_j =0$ are orthogonal."
Let $ \Pi_j= \frac{\chi_j(1)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi_j(g)} \pi(g) $ be the projector onto the $ \pi_j $ isotypic subspace of $ \pi $. The map $ \Pi_j: V \to V $ is clearly $ G $-equivariant because conjugating by any $ g $ just reorders the sum.
We can restrict $ \Pi_j: V \to V $ to a map $ \Pi_j: V_i \to \Pi_j(V_i) $. Since $ V_i $ is irreducible, the image of this new map must be irreducible (or $ 0 $). But recall that $ \Pi_j $ is $ G $-equivariant. So we have a $ G $-equivariant map between irreps. We know $ V_i $ transforms in the irrep $ \pi_i $ and since $ \Pi_j(V_i) $ is in the image of the $ \pi_j $ isotypic projector then $ \Pi_j(V_i) $ must transform in $ \pi_j $ (or else be $ 0$). But Schur's lemma says that a $ G $-equivariant map between non isomorphic irreps must be the $ 0 $ map, thus $ \Pi_j(V_i)=0 $.
So finally we can take the isotypic projector $ \Pi_j $ and obtain $ \langle v_i,v_j \rangle= \langle v_i, \Pi_j v_j \rangle= \langle \Pi_j v_i,  v_j \rangle= \langle 0,v_j \rangle=0 $ which is the desired result.

Any diagonalisable linear operator $N: V \to V$ cuts up $V$ into a direct sum of eigenspaces $V = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}} V_\lambda$ (with only finitely many $V_\lambda$ being nonzero). The operator $N$ is normal if it is diagonalisable, and in addition, the eigenspaces $V_\lambda$ are all orthogonal under whatever inner product is on $V$.
Now let $\pi: G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ be any representation of a finite or compact group. We know through some theory that such a representation is completely reducible, that is it decomposes $V$ into isotypic components $V = \bigoplus_{\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)} V_\chi$, where $V_\chi$ is the sum of all subrepresentations isomorphic to the irrep $\chi$. If $\pi$ is unitary, then the isotypic components $V_\chi$ are all orthogonal under the inner product on $V$.
So the analogies are:

A single operator $N$ vs a collection of operators $\pi: G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$.
Eigenspaces $V_\lambda$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ vs isotypic components $V_\chi$ for $\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$.

There is a way to unify them directly (at least in the case of $G$ finite), which is by looking at $N$ acting on $V$ as a representation of the polynomial algebra $\mathbb{C}[x]$, and $G$ acting on $V$ as a representation of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

do you know any easy proof that if $ \pi $ is unitary then the isotypic components $ V_\chi $ are all orthogonal under the inner product on $ V $?

Sure: let $V_1, V_2 \subseteq V$ be irreps, and consider the orthogonal projector $P_2: V \to V$ which projects to $V_2$. The projector $P_2$ is $G$-equivariant (it is the orthogonal sum of the identity map on the $G$-stable subspaces $V_2$ and $V_2^\perp$), and so restricts to a $G$-equivariant map $P_2': V_1 \to V_2$. If this map is nonzero, then $V_1$ and $V_2$ are isomorphic.
